# How to align the 2nd line with the beginning of 1st line(longer than 2nd line) when the whole thing is right aligned?

Tags: html, css

I have two lines with different lengths. The first one is around 25-40 chars and the second line is around 15-30 chars.

I want both of them to be right-aligned. But I want the beginning of the second line to be under the beginning of the first line no matter the length of the first line. Java Script cannot be used in this case.

What I have:
[image]

What I want:
[image]

The code I have is this

```
<table role="presentation" width="600" class="full" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 600px; margin: auto;" bgcolor="#ffffff" >
   <tr>
      <td class="full" align="center" style="padding-top: 36px; padding-bottom: 38px;">
         <table role="presentation" width="520" align="center" class="width84p" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 600px; margin: auto;">
            <tr>
               <td align="left" valign="top"  style="font-family: Avenir, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height:20px; color:#393a3d;">
                  <span style="font-weight:600;">label1:</span> very lengthy text (20-30 chars)
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td align="left" style="font-family: Avenir, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height:20px; color:#393a3d; padding-top:8px;">
                  <span style="font-weight:600;">label2:</span> short text (5-15 chars)
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Ashok does it need to be in a table?

Comment: @John Not really, I wanted that output. table is better. Else if it can be achievied through other means, that is also good.

Comment: A `table` is not good for this use. There are way better ways to do this.

Comment: Oh, Okay. I am not aware of those. Any help would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

This uses CSS `grid` to get what you're looking for.

```css
.container {
  /* grid */
  display: grid;
  /* two columns: 1fr = remaining space, minmax is set to a width of minimum to max content */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr minmax(min-content,max-content);
}

.content {
  /* content elements start a the second column */
  grid-column-start: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <span style="font-weight:600;">label2:</span> short text (5-15 chars)
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <span style="font-weight:600;">label2:</span> long text more here here (15-40 chars)
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is wrapping the text in 2 lines. I dont want them to be wrapped. It should be like in the the image in the question, but just right aligned.

Comment: Updated answer. _But I want the beginning of the second line to be under the beginning of the first line no matter the length of the first line_ That's why I had the label on the top of each line. I misunderstood what you wanted.

Comment: Very sorry If I am unclear. That is just right aligning the text. I want the label2 to be exactly under label1 as in the above image. (Also added that image in the question. ). So essentially that leaves white space after the 2nd line. Thank you for taking the time on this.

Comment: @Ashok you can use `grid` for this. Simplifies the markup. You basically make the `container` a grid parent, and then the `content` grid children that start in the second column.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `tbody` tag and wrap the `tr` tags with it. And also write down styles `float: right`:

```
<tbody style="float: right">
   <tr>
      <td align="left" valign="top"  style="font-family: Avenir, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height:20px; color:#393a3d;">
         <span style="font-weight:600;">label1:</span> very lengthy text (20-30 chars)
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td align="left" style="font-family: Avenir, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height:20px; color:#393a3d; padding-top:8px;">
         <span style="font-weight:600;">label2:</span> short text (5-15 chars)
     </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

```html
<table role="presentation" width="600" class="full" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 600px; margin: auto;" bgcolor="#ffffff" >
   <tr>
      <td class="full" align="center" style="padding-top: 36px; padding-bottom: 38px;">
         <table role="presentation" width="520" align="center" class="width84p" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 600px; margin: auto;">
          <tbody style="float: right">
            <tr>
               <td align="left" valign="top"  style="font-family: Avenir, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height:20px; color:#393a3d;">
                  <span style="font-weight:600;">label1:</span> very lengthy text (20-30 chars)
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td align="left" style="font-family: Avenir, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height:20px; color:#393a3d; padding-top:8px;">
                  <span style="font-weight:600;">label2:</span> short text (5-15 chars)
               </td>
            </tr>
             </tbody>
         </table>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

If not using a table, this is really easy to do with `float: right;` here's a little example I made for you:

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color:yellow;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class= "wrapper">
    <span>very lengthy text (20-30 chars)</span><br>
    <span>short text (5-15 chars)</span>
</div>
```

And here's a little bit more code for you so you can get an idea of how things can be laid out relative to other things:

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color:yellow;
  float: right;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color:#DBE5D5;
}

.leftside{
  float: left;
  background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div class = "container">
<div class="leftside">
Im on the left
</div>
  <div class= "wrapper">
  <span>very lengthy text (20-30 chars)</span><br>
  <span>short text (5-15 chars)</span>
  </div>
</div>
```